# MySQL many to many, fetch values

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables in database: `wp_connections`, `wp_connections_terms` and `wp_connections_relationships`. First one contains companies, `id` and `organization` columns, and `organization` contains company's name. Second table has 'term_id' column as PK, and `name` column for branch name.

Third table is an intermediary table, which contains FKs: `term_taxonomy_id -> wp_connections_terms__term_id` and `entry_id -> wp_connections__id`.

What I'm trying to do is to have all `wp_connections` rows from the db, and JOIN `wp_connections_terms` data, both `term_id` and `name` to each related row.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT id, 
       organization, 
       options, 
       term_id, 
       name 
FROM   wp_connections 
       JOIN wp_connections_term_relationships 
         ON wp_connections.id = wp_connections_term_relationships.entry_id 
       JOIN wp_connections_terms 
         ON wp_connections_terms.term_id = 
            wp_connections_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
ORDER  BY organization ASC
```

This query gives me data, but some rows are duplicated. I have 62 rows in `wp_connections` table, but I get 74 results with this query. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a link to sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a71d33/2 with schema and some data. I've cut the columns we don't need for this usecase, due to input characters count limitation.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong.  You simply have multiple rows that match in the tables being joined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do I make those return only unique results? I assume that's because relationship table can have referrences to both tables more than once.

Comment: @D-Shih it multiplies each row from wp_connections by the number of that row's id count in wp_term_relationships table. So if an entry for id 5 is in 7 rows in relationship table, I get 7 times said row from wp_connections

Comment: Post it in SqlFiddle with tables created with data in them. Then, by seeing the data we can fix it for you.

Comment: I've eddited. Link to sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a71d33/2

Comment: As you said, this is a many-to-many relationship, so you should expect your data to behave like this. Can you show us what exactly you want your output to be? 
Using a `GROUP BY id` shows unique `wp_connections.organization` values, but as expected,  other linked columns will only be shown once, which doesn't look like what your expected output will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be that some rows of some one table  is related  to more then one rows  in the others tables so the query return duplicated  rows ..

If you need  distinct result then add  this to the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id, 
   organization, 
   options, 
   term_id, 
   name 
FROM   wp_connections 
   JOIN wp_connections_term_relationships 
     ON wp_connections.id = wp_connections_term_relationships.entry_id 
   JOIN wp_connections_terms 
     ON wp_connections_terms.term_id = 
        wp_connections_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
 ORDER  BY organization ASC
```

Comment: DISTINCT in this case does not work. It displays literally same results.

Comment: then are the rows  not duplicated ... so update your question  add  a proper data sample  you actual result and the expected  result  ..

Comment: as I said this is many to many relationship, meaning that in mentioned intermediary table, you can have an entry_id multiple times, and an term_taxonomy_id multiple times. One company can be assigned to many branches, and an branch can have many companies assigned to it. The problem is that intermediary table join. One row from wp_connections is duplicated n times, where n is the number of said row's ID rows count in relationship table.

Comment: if you don't post a valid sample  is impossible eval  your situation  .. DISTINCT .. can't return duplicated  rows .. at least in one columns each rows  must have different values .. ..

Comment: post a valid sample of what?